# PHP XML get attributes of item by attribute value

Tags: php, xml

I have an **`xml`** file that has this structure:

```
<products>
    <group>
        <product id="853" symbol="XYZ123" stock="73"></product>
        <product id="941" symbol="ERX412" stock="57"></product>
        <product id="1960" symbol="UIX981" stock="21"></product>
        ...
    </group>
</products>
```

I need to get only certain products out of it so I'm using **this code**:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( 'products.xml', null, LIBXML_NOCDATA );
$ids = [853, 1960];
foreach($ids as $id){
    $data = $xml->xpath('//group/product[@id='.$id.']');
    $arr[$id] = $data;
}
```

This works well to get a full `<product>` but I need to get only the stock of certain products(ex. for `product id 853` `stock = 73`).

What's the best way to get that done?

Comment: @NigelRen neither one solved it :)

Comment: OK - if you have tried something and it doesn't work, try adding what you did and what happened or didn't happen.

Comment: @NigelRen done, it's not the best answer in the world but at least it works for me...

Comment: If you have solved this yourself, then you can add it as an answer and (after a couple of days I think) accept it.  Helps to show others how it can be solved.

Comment: @NigelRen i'm not going to add this as an answer cause i know that there is a better option, i just can't figure it out for now...this is just an improvisation for now

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach :

```
$attributes = $data->attributes();
```

This method returns an array of attributes, in your case `id`, `symbol` and `stock`. Then you can retrieve the `stock` attribute value with :

```
$attributes['stock']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode` with `json_encode` and `simplexml_load_string` OR `simplexml_load_file`

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),true);//use `simplexml_load_file`
foreach($array['group']['product'] as $v){
  $cur    = $v['@attributes']['id'];
  $stock  = $v['@attributes']['stock'];
  in_array($cur, $ids) ? ($res[$cur] = $stock) : '';
}
print_r($res);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/5PZYp

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor tweak to your code, the main part is the way you get the data from your XPath result.  As it will be a list of matches - you need to use `[0]` as well as `['stock']` to get the stock attribute.  Finally convert it to a string to make sure you get a value rather than an SimpleXMLElement ...

```
foreach($ids as $id){
    $data = $xml->xpath('//group/product[@id='.$id.']');
    $arr[$id] = (string)$data[0]['stock'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted a solution on behalf of the question author, to move it from the question post)*.

I ended up looping through the elements:

```
foreach($xml->group->product as $element){
    $xml_id = (string)$element->attributes()->id;

    if(in_array($xml_id, $ids)){
        $arr[$xml_id] = $element->attributes()->stock;
    }
}
```

This is for sure not the best idea in the world, but it works for me. I'll come with an update if I ever find an answer that doesn't require looping through the way I do it right now.